# Distance Measurement Using Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, distance, tracking, vuforia

I want to scan an image target and start tracking camera movements. now if I go outside of the room lets say 200 meters away. the app should show me that I am 200 meters away from the scanned image.

Simply, is this possible in Vuforia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisely and reliably? Most likely not. From my experience, both orientation and position tend to drift over time if you're not looking at the same area for a while. It also depends a lot on how fast you're moving the device. If the device sleeps, tracking is also lost unless it can find some tracking points it has seen before in the session.

If your goal is to measure large distances, you are probably better of using the device's location-service (GPS+Wifi-tracking). You could still use Vuforia to trigger the start location if that is important. If this is a route you would like to go, there are also plugins on the asset store that can help you get started (although none of them are free):
[AR GPS asset store plugins](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/ar-gps-location-134882?q=ar%20gps&orderBy=0)

Please describe your problem and goal more in-depth in case this wasn't helpful.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I actually do not want to use GPS, because this is an indoor navigation case. Simply I want to scan the image (the start point) on the first floor and want to go to the 4th floor. now the camera should show me how many meters upside I went? (Y axis in the real world). or maybe how meters I went left or right from the image? (X-axis in the real world).